# Can I add a Hypervisor to my Windows Desktop and still use the consoles?

Tags: esxi, xen

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate (for business) and would like to slip Xen or free ESXi (vSphere Hypervisor) in between my current Windows image, and the hardware layer, and still be able to use my consoles to login to this and any other guest VMs. I am unable to do this with the Windows Server Core Hyper-V. Can I do this with Xen or ESXi? Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having some trouble parsing your question, but you seem to be interested in converting your win7 to virtual, and running it alongside other VMs on an ESXI server.

You can certainly do this, but because both [Xen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen) and [ESXI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESX) are Type-1 (bare-metal) [hypervisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor), they do not present a real desktop to the interactive user, so your consoles will have to be run on a different physical machine. Once a box has been booted to either of these Kernels, they present almost no user interface.

From what you are describing, you either need a Type-2 hypervisor like [VMWare Workstation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation) or [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), or to use two machines; one to run the hypervisor and VMs, and another to run an OS that supports remote console utilities like [vCenter/vSphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_vSphere) client, or remote [desktop sharing applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) like [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), [MS Terminal services client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection), [Teamviewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer), etc.

Comment: Thanks Frank. You understood pretty much. Basically I want to run the type I Hypervisor, my main Windows as a VM, and on occasion some other guests, all on the same machine that has two consoles that I would also like to use as the guest consoles. I was hoping the hypervisor would support a guest console directly like RDP or VNC. Both can be used outside of Windows.

Comment: I can say with certianty that you cannot do this with ESXI. you can't do much of anything when you are sitting in front of an ESXI host except configure its IP address and a handful of other items via a menu driven UI. there is no way to launch additional apps. From what I've seen of Zen, its the same way. even the hosts administration has to be remotely managed, beyond network settings, and and enabling certain remote shells (like SSH) for access.

Comment: Sure would be nice if these hypervisor consoles would support VNC and RDP guest consoles. Would not be that hard to do and would be quite useful esp. in a powerful desktop situation. Would be a whole new market for them that a Type-2 does not address.

Comment: How is VMWare Workstation, installed on your current Windows OS, not do what you want?  I have (for years) run Win and the OS on the box, and occasionally run VMs for various purposes.

Comment: @Dave, IPMI lets me operate a headless server from another machine, including full VGA screen image.  It's done in the hardware.

Comment: @jdlugosz - I suppose it and Hyper-V with Win8 come close but what I actually want is to be able to have a type I hyper be top level so I can boot whichever OS I want from a VMDK or VHD. I don't want a second machine to access a headless server, I want my desktop machine to be the non-headless server and to allow me to use the consoles to access the VMs that are available. This apparently is not implemented in any of the hypers but no reason it could not be.

Comment: @dave I think you are looking for the same thing as me.  The bare booter would need the graphics driver to provide an abstract display emulation tomthe VM's.  Or, the display needes to be passed-through to the VM, which makes the VM have real harsdware drivers.  Now discovering a new display (or fallback generic SVGA) is not too bad, so maybe it's OK to not virtualize that. [http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multi-headed-VMWare-Gaming-Setup-564](here is 4 consoles), each for a VM, onnthe same box running the bare-metal server.

Comment: @Dave, it really sounds like you want to run your server the way you would use VMWare workstation, or Virtualbox or hyper-v. While they are type-2, they fit your workflow perfectly. Why not use one of them?

Comment: @Frank - I guess I'm just being idealistic. The point here is I don't want my hypervisor to be dependent on the desktop I want to run. I want to run my desktop as a VMDK or VHD and not have to worry about maintaining it in order to use the hypervisor. This way I can migrate to a new desktop OS yet boot the old one should I desire. I think all the Type-I vendors are missing an opportunity here. What they should offer is a HyperI install that turns the current OS into a guest, and then natively support an RDP or VMC client to get at the old Windows or Linux guest that used to own the machine.

Comment: @frank -  I think any of the hyperI vendors would greatly increase their desktop usage if they would offer this. Kind of an ultimate multi boot ability...imo they got it upside down with Win8 and VMware workstation.